# How to set a JDBC PreparedStatement parameter for an Oracle CHAR field?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I think I am missing something obvious with my Oracle JDBC prepared statement. I am trying to create a `PreparedStatement` that selects column `A` from `TABLE` where `B` is the parameter. For example, this is what I've boiled down the test code too:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
final Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(<Oralce JDBC connection stuff>);
final PreparedStatement findStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT A FROM TABLE WHERE B = ?");

findStatement.setString(1, "TEST");

final ResultSet results = findStatement.executeQuery();
results.next();

System.out.println(results.getString("A"));
```

Now this doesn't work, I currently get `java.sql.SQLException: Result set after last row` because of the `ResultSet` being empty.

However, this works:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
final Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(<Oralce JDBC connection stuff>);
final PreparedStatement findStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT A FROM TABLE WHERE B = 'TEST'");

final ResultSet results = findStatement.executeQuery();
results.next();

System.out.println(results.getString("A"));
```

Notice how I hard coded the `WHERE` statement with a string.

Anything obvious I am missing?

My maven dependency is defined as:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
  <version>12.1.0.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

Column `B` is defined as a `CHAR(50)`

Here is some debug information from Oracle

```
select
  s.sql_text,
  bc.position,
  bc.value_string
from v$sql s
  left join v$sql_bind_capture bc
  on bc.sql_id = s.sql_id
  and bc.child_number = s.child_number
where
  s.sql_text like 'SELECT A%'
order by s.sql_id, bc.position;
```

With output

```
SQL_TEXT                             | Position                       | Value_String
SELECT A FROM TABLE WHERE B = :1     | 1                              | TEST
SELECT A FROM TABLE WHERE B = 'TEST' | <null>                         | <null>
```

Comment: Maybe because in the first version you're searching for `TEXT` and in the second you're searching for `TEST`.

Comment: @Erik L, if the above statement is true, then this is a big blunder. +1 to kayaman for that.

Comment: If what @Kayaman said is true, this is the kind of problems you solve by "disconnecting" from your work for a couple of hours hahaha

Comment: Sorry! That was a typo in my example, I've fixed it.

Comment: Well that's no fun, you just made the question a lot harder. However, the code seems to be pretty standard JDBC. I can't imagine this being the driver's fault (would be a pretty huge bug).

Comment: Hence why I am here :) I thought this should be straightforward and I've spent way too long staring at it.

Comment: Check on the database side what queries are sent from the client.

Comment: K, I've tried doing that client side but with no luck. I just started trying on the server itself but haven't found the right Oracle query to give me that data yet.

Comment: What's the type of your db field?

Comment: Sorry, read better your question and found it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the definition of your field is `CHAR(50)`, I think you should pad your `String` with blanks.

Comment: What in the blazes....that works!

`findStatement.setString(1, String.format("%1$-50s", "TEST"));`

Comment: Ugh...that's just...horrible. Another reason to stay away from `CHAR`.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @LppEdd answer you can also do this for setting the parameter:

```
((OraclePreparedStatement)findStatement).setFixedCHAR(1, "TEST");
```